# I want to connect to an Oracle database with my ASP.NET MVC web application

Tags: asp.net-mvc, oracle, asp.net-mvc-5

I am developing an ASP.NET MVC web application and aiming to connect it to an Oracle database. I have downloaded Oracle Managed Data Access and installed ODAC on my PC, and have configured TNS settings.

However, when attempting to add a model using ADO.NET, only SQL options appear, whereas I require Oracle to conduct CRUD operations and other tasks.

Comment: How did you install the ODP.NET Managed driver?

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit My company's IT department downloaded ODP.NET.

Comment: Depending on what you are trying to do -- you don't mention if you are using Visual Studio or what --- if it requires a VS UI, you may need to install Oracle Developer Tools for Visual Studio extension.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your IT department did not configure the ODP.NET Managed driver.

Have a look at your Registry, you should find entries like these:

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\WOW6432Node\Microsoft\.NETFramework\v4.0.30319\AssemblyFoldersEx\Oracle.ManagedDataAccess]
@="c:\\oracle\\product\\19c\\ODP.NET\\managed\\common"

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\WOW6432Node\Microsoft\.NETFramework\v4.0.30319\AssemblyFoldersEx\Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.EntityFramework6]
@="c:\\oracle\\product\\19c\\ODP.NET\\managed\\common\\EF6"
```

Either add them manually or run the config script at `...\ODP.NET\managed\x64\configure.bat true`